# Building a Register form using core data using swift 4

Tags: swift4

I want to build a signup form using core data in swift 4 .
However,I am getting an error: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
 @IBAction func registerfunction(_ sender: Any) {
        let userEmail = usernamefield.text;
        let userPassword = passwordfield.text;
        let userConfirmPassword = confirmfield.text;
        let city = cityfield.text;
        let dateofbirth = dateofbirthfield.text;
        let gender = genderfield.text;

      var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "User")
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
               if let error = error {

                fatalError("Unresolved error, \((error as NSError).userInfo)")
               }
        })
            return container
        }()


        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext as! NSManagedObjectContext
        let context = managedObjectContext

        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: context) as NSManagedObject
        newUser.setValue(usernamefield.text, forKey: "name")
        newUser.setValue(passwordfield.text, forKey: "password")
        newUser.setValue(confirmfield.text, forKey: "confirmpassword")
        newUser.setValue(genderfield.text, forKey: "gender")
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {}
        print(newUser)
        print("Object Saved.")
```

And here is my app delegate code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "User")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {

                fatalError("Unresolved error, \((error as NSError).userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance

I imported CoreData,and I am using the file Users.xcdatamodeld

Comment: You use `as!` in three places; which one is crashing?

Comment: Everywhere it is crashing :    ; closure #1 () -> __ObjC.NSPersistentContainer in variable initialization expression of whnewapp.AppDelegate.persistentContainer : __ObjC.NSPersistentContainer at AppDelegate.swift:17